# Symfony - Doctrine not generating entity

Tags: symfony, model, doctrine, entity, schema

i have a quite primitve problem:

I created an Entity in my Symfony App:

src/AppBundle/Model/Article/Article.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Model\Article;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article {

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length="255", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

}
```

When i type in console:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
```

it prints:

```
Bundle "AppBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

And when i type:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Model/Article/Article
```

it prints:

```
Class "AppBundle\Model\Article\Article" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.
```

Anybody has some idea how to solve this?

I already followed some solutions on stackoverflow like changing or turning off cache/clearing cache/ etc.. but none works.

Thanks and Greetings!

Answer (score 6):

Probably Doctrine doesn't know about these mappings.
Have you created this bundle with a generator?

Check your `config.yml` in app/config, you should have an entry under following keys structure:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    mappings:
      AppBundle: ~
```

**Edit:** 
Ok, you use custom structure.
Default namespace should look like that:

```
AppBundle\Entity
```

So full class name should be `AppBundle\Entity\Article`

If you want to stick with custom mappings, check [configuration docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration).

Comment: I changed automapping: true for the mappings and worked, ty

Answer (score 0):

You should add all your Entities in the Entity Folder, remember Entity and Model are different concepts. You can create others folders like Model, Handlers, Managers. Another important thing is not to confuse Data Base with Object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you do not use `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\SimpleAnnotationReader` class. Instead `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader` should be used.

Simple reader doesn't support `@ORM\Annotation`, only `@Annotation`.